# Common region for two pages in an 100 page application

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am trying to find an optimal way to implement a common region, common to multiple pages (but not all pages) in a huge multi page application.

I understand the concept of Page 0. Common regions can be included in page 0 and proper server side conditions can be used to stop rendering these regions from rendering in all pages. But my concern is that the server side condition will be evaluated for every page every time the page is loaded whereas those regions are used only in, say, two pages in a 500 page application . Won't that be an overhead on every page?

Please note that the common region has dynamic actions, PL/SQL Code etc like any other region and so including that regions in page template will not be an option.

Please help me figure out an optimal way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be an overhead, but if you still with the declarative "low code" options, it's just like another "if" statement, as opposed to code that's interpreted live.

http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2013/05/performance-of-apex-conditions.html

It will be slow for the same reason we compile plugin code into packages.

http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2016/04/improving-plsql-performance-in-apex.html

I think you can be confident of application performance on the global page using a condition like this

[image]

If you're really concerned, duplicate the component on each page - you only need to do it twice. And it will just be the meta-data, right? Since the PL/SQL would be just an call to a package...?

Comment: Thanks @scott. I am aware of that server side condition.I am being too miser to even allow that overhead. Regarding Duplication, there is lot of JavaScript as well as PL/SQL on each item in the common region and any future changes changes to the region would mean change in all pages.

Comment: That's a lot of content you appear to be embeddin within the APEX component, instead of abstracted into a package or JS file. Unless it's an APEX attribute changing, it should be one change.

Comment: Yes @scott I agree that higher level of abstraction (JS files and PLSQL procedure) will address the issues caused by duplicating the region in all pages.

Comment: From what is available as of today, I think we will have to use page 0 for implementation of such common regions and compromise on the little overhead it might have on every other page the component is not being used.

Comment: In my experience, when using declarative options, the compromise is nominal. It's using PL/SQL expressions that can get you into trouble.